# Trivial *Pet*suit Event

Tags: discussion, event, data-explorer

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/pets/queries) (SEDE) offers many interesting insights into our site that would be impossible to gain otherwise.

For one month (June 2021) we want to extract one interesting or unusual fact about the site each day.

Inspired by a discussion in chat.

---

Even users who aren't familiar with SEDE can participate. Click the link above to open the SEDE interface. At the top center of the page you can click [Queries], which lists existing queries made by other users. You can browse the headlines and try a few of them. Some don't work well for Pets because they were written for bigger sites, but most should at least get 1 result.

Comment: What a nice idea! All the support and encouragement you need from the [SEDE chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8893820#8893820) !

Comment: Trivial fursuit? No, that's a different stack. (Life, liberty, and the fursuit of haffiness?))

Answer (score 5):

The event ended on 2021-07-01. I want to thank anyone who participated, especially Nai45 for comming up with the idea and rene for contributing several queries in our chat room.

These facts have been compiled by various users.

### General Pets.SE Trivia

- As of today (2021-06-30) there are 16,016 users registered on Pets.
  6,885 of them have enough reputation to comment on posts.
  1,896 have enough rep. to downvote.
  266 have enough rep. to create new tags and retag questions.
  58 have enough rep. to edit posts and bypass the quality review.
  8 have enough rep. to access moderator tools.
- As of today there are 7441 questions on Pets, of which 688 (9%) are closed.
- Oct 2013 was the month when most questions (350) were asked.
  Oct 2018 and Mar 2018 were the months when most questions were closed (24 each).
- **51** people [followed the Area **51** proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/badges/66/precognitive).
- Until today, there was not a single link to [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/) in any question or answer... I had to change that. https://xkcd.com/413/
- There are currently 3562 users who have asked only 1 question and only 2 users who have asked more than 100 questions: [James Jenkins](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/13) and probably Yvette Colomb alias user6796 (just guessing because user is deleted now).
- The questions with the longest time between being tweeted on Twitter by the official Pets.SE account and hitting HNQ (only for posts where both events happened) are:
  [Cat is tipping over bed-side lamps during the night](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/23833) which became HNQ 64h after being tweeted and
  [Goldfish behaviour after medication](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/24042) which became HNQ 488 days *before* being tweeted.
- There are at least 22 users on Pets who have user names supporting Monica.
- The most prolific editor is user [lila](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/17671/lila) with a total number of 2474 edits. That's more than three times the number of edits by "Community" (2nd place, 716 edits total).
- This answer on [How can I measure the weight of my cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/21977)
   has a score/post's length ratio of 0.66 which is significantly higher than the post on the [second position](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/14) in that [list](https://data.stackexchange.com/pets/query/1424659).

### Tags

- Questions on Pets have on average 2.8 tags. Most questions (2577) have 2 tags and least questions (670) have 5 tags.
- The tags with the highest percentages of unanswered questions are
  [health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) with 13.11% questions unanswered and
  [aquarium](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarium) with 12.88% questions unanswered.
- The tag [attire](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attire) has the highest average score on both questions (avg. score of 34) and answers (avg. score of 11.86)
- On average, questions with the tag [communication](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) have the highest score with 8 upvotes (net).

### Voting and Accepting Answers

- The only users with at least 3k reputation who never cast a downvote are [Kate Paulk](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/159/kate-paulk) and [Mario](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/3350/mario).
- The user with the highest rep who has voted the least is user [Mario](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/3350/mario?tab=profile) with 5,025 reputation points and two votes.
- The most evil user (aka highest downvote to upvote ratio) is user [Failed-community](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/541/failed-community), who has cast 102 downvotes and only 17 upvotes.
- The user who has cast the most close, reopen, (un)delete, (un)lock, (un)protect and migrate votes is [James Jenkins](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/13) with a total of 238 votes.
- The user who has cast the most up and downvotes is [lila](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/17671) with 9,588 upvotes and 1064 downvotes.
- The most controversial post on Pets is [Can I give my cat human medicine?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/726/12501). It received overall 11 upvotes, 7 downvotes, 6 close votes, 3 reopen votes and 8 comments.
- The user with the highest percentage of self-accepts (to accept your own answer) is [Spidercat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/481/spidercat) with almost 29% of answers being self-accepted.
- The worst leeches (users with the most questions asked and least votes cast) are [user10731](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/10731/user10731) with 14 questions (0 answers accepted) and 0 votes and [gstestso](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/5736/gstestso) with 18 questions (18 answers accepted) and 1 upvote.
- The user with the highest answer to accepted answer ratio is [Mozein](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/1242) with 75% of their answers accepted (15 out of 20).
- The question with the longest time between being asked and accepting an answer is [this one](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/946), which first had any answer accepted 3 years and 8 months after it was asked.

### Reputation and Bounties

- The highest ranked user in terms of reputation is [James Jenkins](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/13) with approximately 28.700 points.
- User [Zaralynda](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/224) spent the most reputation points as bounties with a total of 3,200 points.
- The most reputation ever gained in a single day was 540 by [Flater](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/10539) - 500 as bounty and 40 by votes.
- The first user to ever gain 1k reputation after the site started was [woliveirajr](http://pets.stackexchange.com/users/66) 8 days after the site started.
  The first user to ever gain 10k reputation after the site started was [John Cavan](http://pets.stackexchange.com/users/32) 15 months after the site started.
- Of all users who wrote at least 10 answers, [Dennis Graves](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/20) has the highest score with an average of 15.62 over 13 answers.
  Of all users who wrote at least 5 answers, [iKlsR](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/52) has the highest score with an average of 21.33 over 6 answers.
- Of all users with at least 200 reputation, the top 1% share 152,632 reputation (21.3%), while the remaining 99% share 562,681 reputation (78.6%).

### Questions and Answers

- There are currently 40 answers that were posted at the same time as the question.
- The most viewed questions are [Why does my dog get stuck to the female after mating?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/936) and [How do I tell the sex of a bearded dragon?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/5923), both the only questions with more than 380k views.
- The answer which received the most downvotes (8 in total) without being deleted is [this one](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/19459/12501). It's also the accepted answer with the lowest score.
- The question which received the most downvotes (16 in total) without being closed or deleted is [How can I stop my kitten from growing?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/25436)
- The longest answer is [this one](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/13451) and has 20,379 characters (individual letters).
- [How can I stop my cat over grooming & pulling hair?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/9714/12501) is currently closed question with the most favorites (3).
- There are 2 answers on Pets with a length of <50 characters and a score ≥0:
  [What do I do with a dog who vomits while recovering from surgery?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/2097/12501)
  [I have two kittens and need an answer on determining hair length](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/16754/12501)
- The user who wrote the most answers is [Elmy](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/12501) with 457 answers.
- The user who wrote the most answers and never asked a question is [Rebecca RVT](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/7526/rebecca-rvt) with 288 answers.

### Badges

- Only one user on Pets has the "Socratic" badge (ask a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintain a positive question record): [James Jenkins](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/13).
- Only one person has the "Sportsmanship" badge (upvote 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score): [James Jenkins](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/13).
- Only one person on the Pets SE has ["Steward"](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/badges/83/steward) badge: [Trond Hansen](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/7612/trond-hansen) (awarded for reviewing first posts).
- Only 4 of current Pets SE users have gold tag badge; those users are: Trond Hansen for [cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats), Zaralynda for [cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats), Kai for [cats](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cats), and Elmy for [dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs). Only Trond Hansen and Kai get to use their badge, though; Zaralynda is inactive and for Elmy it is redundant.
- As of today, only 2 users have ever earned "Great Answer" badge (awarded for answer with score of 100 or more) and no user has ever earned "Great Question" badge (awarded for question with score of 100 or more).
- The most popular asker is [Ash](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/53), who received "Popular question" badges for 30 of 37 questions.